# Is there a Typescript editor for Android?

Tags: android, github, typescript, ide, editor

I see that this is not a specific progamming question, however I have asked it in a binary way so perhaps this will pass scrutiny.

I've been using Quoda on my Android phone and have started needing to edit .ts / Typescript files, which it does not support.  At the moment I am using SGit which just opens whatever Android app to edit a file type based on the extension. Quoda (and general text editors) can open a .ts if opened within the app, however do not have syntax highlighting.

So I have searched high and low, the only .ts editor I have found is CodeAnywhere, which is really great in a desktop browser but definitely has a few issues on the Android app version.

So, the question is NOT 'can you recommend one', it's can you tell me of any obscure apps apart from CodeAnywhere please? Or I suppose another way of editing .ts from github on my phone?

Comment: I created alm.tools : http://alm.tools/ it does open up in chrome but is *really really small* :)

Comment: That's really cool! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use stackblitz.com, its almost exactly the same as VSCode and also allows you to make Angular and React apps. If you add it to your homescreen it looks just like a native app

Answer (score 0):

You can run TypeScript programs on Termux.
Follow these steps to run TypeScript in Termux.

1. Download and install official "Termux" app from F-Droid Repository.
2. Install Node.js in termux using the command `pkg install nodejs`
3. Install TypeScript using command `npm install typescript`
4. Install a code editor like Micro/ Nano using command `pkg install micro`. You can also use any code editor apps like Acode or Quoda.
5. Create a TypeScript file using command `micro hello.ts`
   This will open a editor where you can write your TypeScript code.
6. After writing typescript code, come back to terminal and type `tsc hello.ts` this will compile your TypeScript to JavaScript.
7. Now you can run it using command `node hello.js` and it will show output of your TypeScript code.

Comment: This approach is bad because neither termux editors or android editors support code-completion which is an important feature in Typescript